# Product of matrices constructed via an isometry and an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand a proof which is implicitly using facts about orthogonal projections and isometries, but I don't see precisely how they are being used. I am wondering if someone might be able to help me flesh out some details in a proof which are currently being assumed by the author to be self-evident.

Here is the set-up:

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}_+$, and define $\mathbb{R}^p\cdot M := \{x^TM\text{ }|\text{ }x\in\mathbb{R}^p\} = \text{rowspace}(M)$. We take $n =$ rank$(A)$ (assume w.l.o.g. that $n > 0$) and take any map $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^p\cdot M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ which is a bijective linear map which preserves the standard $\textbf{scalar}$ product (they also say it is an isometry), and let $\pi: \mathbb{R}^q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p\cdot M$ be an orthogonal projection. Here is the claim made via this set-up:

Claim) $M = AB$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ is the matrix with rows $\varphi(M_i)$ for $i = 1,\dots, p$, (where $M_i$ is the $i$-th row of $M$) and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$ is the matrix with columns $\varphi (\pi (e_1)), \dots , \varphi (\pi (e_q))$ (where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^q$)

I have two questions related to this. The first is simply whether the word 'scalar' above is simply a typo and should be replaced with 'inner'. If this is not the case, then I am unaware of what a 'standard scalar product' is, unless it is simply referring to the fact that $\varphi(c\textbf{v}) = c\varphi(\textbf{v})$ (in which case explicitly stating this seems redundant since $\varphi$ was already said to be linear).

Second, and most importantly, I am struggling to understand the Claim. I see that in order for this to be true, I need $\varphi(M_i)^T\varphi(\pi(e_j)) = m_{ij}$ (where $m_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-entry of $M$), but I don't know how to use the hypotheses on $\varphi$ and $\pi$ to achieve this.

What I have so far is that I have taken a basis of $\mathbb{R}^p\cdot M$ using explicit row vectors $M_{i_1},\dots, M_{i_n}$. Then $\varphi (\pi (e_j)) = \varphi (<e_j, M_{i_1}>M_{i_1} + \cdots + <e_j, M_{i_n}>M_{i_n}) = \varphi (m_{i_1j}M_{i_1} + \cdots + m_{i_nj}M_{i_n}) = m_{i_1j}\varphi (M_{i_1}) + \cdots + m_{i_nj}\varphi (M_{i_n})$, and so $\varphi (M_i)^T\varphi (\pi (e_j)) = m_{i_1j}\varphi (M_i)^T\varphi (M_{i_1}) + \cdots + m_{i_nj}\varphi (M_i)^T\varphi (M_{i_n})$. However, I don't know where to go from here. I never used the fact that $\varphi$ is an isometry, but I don't see how that is helpful. Can someone show me how to arrive at the desired conclusion (which is that this quantity equals $m_{ij}$), or show me where I may have gone off track? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To your first question: yes, the term "scalar product" is synonymous to "inner product" in this context.  This is not a typo; it is an alternative usage.

Comment: It looks like your interested in a proof of the existence of a rank factorization.  You might want to take a look at [my proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408444/81360), which is along similar lines to the proof you outline here, but which I find simpler.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ok, thanks I haven’t heard this before. Is ‘scalar product’ referring to the fact that the standard inner product here is the dot product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed suffices to show that $\varphi(M_i)^T \varphi(\pi(e_j)) = m_{ij}$.

First, note that since $\varphi$ preserves inner products (i.e. because $\varphi$ is an isometry), we have
$$
\varphi(M_i)^T\varphi(\pi (e_j)) = M_i^T \pi(e_j).
$$
Second, note that $M_i$ is an element of the rowspace of $M$.  By the definition of an orthogonal projection, $e_j - \pi(e_j)$ is an element of the orthogonal complement to the row-space.  It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
m_{ij} &= M_i^T e_j = M_i^T(\pi(e_j) + (e_j - \pi(e_j))) 
\\ & = M_i^T \pi(e_j) + M_i^T(e_j - \pi(e_j)) = M_i^T \pi(e_j) + 0
\\ & = M_i^T \pi(e_j).
\end{align}
$$
So, $\varphi(M_i)^T\varphi(\pi (e_j)) = M_i^T \pi(e_j) = m_{ij}$, and we have reached the desired conclusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this - this really helped.